# Why is player 2's turn skipped after an incorrect input instead of being allowed another input (2p tictactoe game java)

Tags: java

Basically if player 1 puts in an incorrect move (outside of 1-9) then "Incorrect Input" will be printed and they'll be allowed to try again. I have the same code for player 2 but after printing the error message their turn is skipped and it's back to player one. I'm extremely puzzled on how to solve this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTactoe3 {

    static ArrayList<Integer> playerPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> playerPositions2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[][] gameBoard = {{' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}, 
                              {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'}, 
                              {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}, 
                              {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'}, 
                              {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}};

        printGameBoard(gameBoard);  

        while(true) {
            Scanner move = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter your move (1-9) player one ");
            int playerPos = move.nextInt();
            while(playerPositions.contains(playerPos) || playerPositions2.contains(playerPos)) {
                System.out.println("Position taken");
                playerPos = move.nextInt();
            }

            if(playerPos >= 10 || playerPos <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Input");
                continue;
            }

            placePiece(gameBoard, playerPos, "player 1");
            printGameBoard(gameBoard);

            String result = checkWinner();
            if(result.length() > 0) {
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Enter your move (1-9) player two ");
            int playerPos2 = move.nextInt();
            while(playerPositions.contains(playerPos2) || playerPositions2.contains(playerPos2)) {
                System.out.println("Position taken");
                playerPos2 = move.nextInt();
            }

            if(playerPos2 >= 10 || playerPos2 <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Input");
                continue;
            }

            placePiece(gameBoard, playerPos2, "player 2");  
            printGameBoard(gameBoard);

            result = checkWinner();
            if(result.length() > 0) {
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            }
        }   
    }

    public static void printGameBoard(char[][] gameBoard) {
        for(char[] row : gameBoard) {
            for(char c : row) {
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void placePiece(char[][] gameBoard, int pos, String user) {

        char symbol = ' ';

        if(user.equals("player 1")) {
            symbol = 'X';
            playerPositions.add(pos);
        } else if(user.equals("player 2")) {
            symbol = 'O';
            playerPositions2.add(pos);
        }

        switch(pos) {
        case 1:
            gameBoard[0][0] = symbol;
            break;  
        case 2:
            gameBoard[0][2] = symbol;
            break;  
        case 3:
            gameBoard[0][4] = symbol;
            break;
        case 4:
            gameBoard[2][0] = symbol;
            break;
        case 5:
            gameBoard[2][2] = symbol;
            break;
        case 6:
            gameBoard[2][4] = symbol;
            break;
        case 7:
            gameBoard[4][0] = symbol;
            break;
        case 8:
            gameBoard[4][2] = symbol;
            break;
        case 9:
            gameBoard[4][4] = symbol;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    public static String checkWinner() {

        List topRow = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        List midRow = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
        List botRow = Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9);
        List leftCol = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 7);
        List midCol = Arrays.asList(2, 5, 8);
        List rightCol = Arrays.asList(3, 6, 9);
        List cross1 = Arrays.asList(1, 5, 9);
        List cross2 = Arrays.asList(7, 5, 3);

        List<List> winning = new ArrayList<List>();
        winning.add(topRow);
        winning.add(midRow);
        winning.add(botRow);
        winning.add(leftCol);
        winning.add(midCol);
        winning.add(rightCol);
        winning.add(cross1);
        winning.add(cross2);

        for (List l : winning) {
            if(playerPositions.containsAll(l)) {
                return "Congrats, player 1 wins!";
            }
            else if(playerPositions2.containsAll(l)) {
                return "Congrats, player 2 wins";
            }
        }

        for (List l : winning) {
            if(playerPositions.size() + playerPositions2.size() == 9) {
                return "NOBODY WINS";
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

I'm still very much a beginner at java, apologies if this is very basic. I've found multiple other tictactoe questions on here but none to solve my specific issue.

Comment: `continue` will make the loop start over from the top. Using 2 separate loops is one solution

Comment: `continue` will break out of the current iteration of the loop and start over at the next one.  Hence player one will get prompted again.

Comment: Why does continue do that for player two and not player one? And how would I go about using two separate loops here? That seems kind of difficult for a two player game.

Comment: A continue breaks out of the loop at its current spot and starts over again at the beginning of the loop.  The loop starts with the player 1 input, so it asks for it again. If you use two loops with two continues, the continue in that loop would only break out of that loop and not the while(true){}. That is not the ideal solution, but it would work.

Comment: So by two loops do you mean make two while(true){}s? I tried that but then the loops are entirely separate so it just continues to ask for player one's move over and over until they win and then player two only gets to move once after player one has already won. It seems like there simply isn't a good solution here since it has to loop for this to work